# XML sign - multiple <X509Certificate> nodes

Tags: c#, xml, sign

XML sign - multiple  nodes

I am signing an XML document.

Using:

```
 private SignedXml getSignedXml(string idReference, int step)
    {
      SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(this.xmlDocument);
      signedXml.Signature.Id = "SignatureId";

      signedXml.SigningKey = this.certificate.PrivateKey;
      signedXml.KeyInfo = this.getKeyInfo();
      signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigC14NTransformUrl;
      signedXml.AddReference(this.addInvoiceReference(idReference));

      if (step == 1)
        signedXml.AddObject(this.createQualifyingProperties());
      else
      {
        signedXml.AddObject(this.readQualifyingProperties());
        signedXml.AddReference(this.addSignedPropertiesReference());
      }

      return signedXml;
    }



private KeyInfo getKeyInfo()
     {
          KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
          KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(this.certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
          keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
          return keyInfo;
     }





private DataObject createQualifyingProperties()
    {
      SHA1 cryptoServiceProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
      byte[] sha1 = cryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(this.certificate.RawData);

      XNamespace xds = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#";
      XNamespace ds = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";
      XElement qualifyingProperties = new XElement("Object",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xds", xds),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ds", ds),
        new XElement(xds + "QualifyingProperties",
          new XAttribute("Target", "#SignatureId"),
          new XElement(xds + "SignedProperties",
            new XAttribute("Id", "SignedPropertiesId"),
            new XElement(xds + "SignedSignatureProperties",
              new XElement(xds + "SigningTime", this.timeStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")),
              new XElement(xds + "SigningCertificate",
                new XElement(xds + "Cert",
                  new XElement(xds + "CertDigest",
                    new XElement(xds + "DigestMethod", new XAttribute("Algorithm", SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url)),
                    new XElement(xds + "DigestValue", Convert.ToBase64String(sha1))),
                  new XElement(xds + "IssuerSerial",
                    new XElement(ds + "X509IssuerName", this.certificate.IssuerName.Name),
                    new XElement(ds + "X509SerialNumber", Hex2Dec.Convert(this.certificate.SerialNumber))))),
              new XElement(xds + "SignaturePolicyIdentifier",
                new XElement(xds + "SignaturePolicyImplied", string.Empty))))));

      DataObject dataObject = new DataObject
      {
        Data = qualifyingProperties.GetXmlNode().FirstChild.SelectNodes("."),
      };

      return dataObject;
    }
```

Problem is this is its creating XML signature like this:

```
<KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>YYYYYY</X509Certificate>
        <X509Certificate>XXXXXX</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

It should be like this:

```
<KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>YYYYYY</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

Another thing to note is that with certificate A it creates only one node but with certificate B i am getting a second node.

Comment: What should the xml look like with two Certificates?  Your example only has one.

Comment: Sorry. I wan't clear ... i am not using 2 certificates. I am using two different certificates. With first one i am getting correct nodes, but if i try different one (a second one) my code generates 2 nodes under <X509Data> (check XML examples).

Comment: if(signedXml.KeyInfo == null) signedXml.KeyInfo = this.getKeyInfo();